# Unable to set observable result to local variable - undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am new to Angular.
I have a service class which has Subject event which is triggered from component A.
Then I am redirected automatically to component B to subscribe to this event and extract its information to local variables. The result - They are undefined outside the scope of .subscribe() method.

This is the code in component B

```
 ngOnInit(): void {

        this.editUserForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            userName: ['Enter username'],
            firstname: ['Enter first name'],
            lastname: ['Enter last name'],
            email: ['Enter email']
        })
           this.userService.getEditUserInfoEvent().subscribe({
            next:((editUserInfo) => 
                this.setEditFormEventValues(editUserInfo))
        })
    }

    private setEditFormEventValues(userInfo: IGetUserModel) {
      this.id = userInfo.id;
      this.editUserForm.patchValue({
        userName:  userInfo.userName,
        firstname:  userInfo.firstname,
        lastname: userInfo.lastname,
        email: userInfo.email
      })
    }
```

Is this the normal behavior and how can I extract the data, effectively?
If I try to read the data of this.id outside these 2 methods - **it is undefined**
Somewhere I read about the .map method but I am not sure how to implement it, exactly?
Any help will be appreciated - more than 5 hours I am trying to solve this problem.

Comment: where are you trying to access the value ? can you provide a https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular example ?

Comment: Sorry. I uploaded wrong code. Will update it in 1 minute.

Comment: @fastAsTortoise I am unable to upload it right now. Is there any additional information you need to post it here?

Comment: where is it being undefined ? when are you accessing it ? it is going to be undefined if you are trying to access it before its being set. Because from code it looks like you are setting it when your service is finished calling api so until that is done that will stay undefined.

Comment: For example - if I try to log this.id inside the subscribe body it has the correct value. 
In my case I need this Id to later make PUT request to update user information and I pass this Id as the url. But the Id gets undefined.
In the tutorial of Deborah Kurata she does this procedure similarly.

Comment: create an id field in the formgroup and set that id in your patchvalue so next time you submit it will be there and you can check if id is there do put or else do post

Comment: Is `getEditUserInfoEvent()` returning a `Subject`? If yes, maybe take a look at either `BehaviorSubject` (most likely) or `ReplaySubject` (also fair).

Comment: It is subject yes. I will check the others.

Comment: Thank you @JoãoGhignatti - you "da real mvp". This was my problem. I fixed it. Everything is working fine. Thank you so much.
The problem was that the event fired long before the subscribers exist - therefore the event is disregarded. I switched to BehaviorSubject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay guys.
I've found my mistake.
The mistake was that by event as a type was Subject. And that's the whole problem. When I send the event with Subject, the listeners are in another component and yet to be constructed. When a Subject does not have real listeners the event is disregarded.
That's why I changed to behavior subject. It caches the last event and sends it when a subscriber is actively listening.
Thank you for your cooperation.